# database migration code generator

Tags: c#, code-generation, database-migration, migratordotnet

I want to introduce database migrations into my project and would like to be able to generate my initial migration scripts from the database. I was wondering if there are any code generation tools around to do this? I was thinking of using migrator.net but am happy to use anything so long as I can get a tool to generate code for it.

Answer (score 2):

[Wizardby](http://code.google.com/p/octalforty-wizardby/) can perform [reverse-engineering](http://code.google.com/p/octalforty-wizardby/wiki/CommandLineReference#reverseengineer) of existing database schema.

Answer (score 0):

Data Dude (ie: [Visual Studio Team System Database Edition](http://blogs.msdn.com/gertd/archive/2007/11/21/visual-studio-team-system-2008-database-edition.aspx)) does a very, very good job of this.  It allows automatic migration code generation through multiple versions, as well as building full scripts off an existing DB.

Answer (score 0):

[Fluent Migrator](https://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator/) can do this now too

http://computeristsolutions.com/blog/posts/2011/4/dumping-existing-schema-with-fluentmigrator